How to compute a weighted mean as a measure of central tendency?
Imagine I have data points in triplicates, as follows
$$
L=\begin{pmatrix}
p_{11} & p_{12} & p_{13}\\
p_{21} & p_{22} & p_{23}\\
& \vdots &\\
p_{n1} & p_{n2} & p_{n3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
What is the best way to filter this data, so that I remove outliers and end up with a vector of best-fit values
$$
\tilde{L}=(\tilde{p}_1,\tilde{p}_2,\cdots,\tilde{p}_n)
$$
Thoughts: For example, if I have the plot

I could naturally take the mean of these values (in blue)

but clearly, at $n=5$ I have a potential outlier, which could be removed for a better fit. What would be the ideal technique to assign a weighted mean to each triplicate based on the overall dataset, possibly based on the average standard deviation between triplicates? I have heard about Cook's distance, but I am not too sure how to apply it here.
Any ideas?

If your objective really is a better fit, as you write; and if you are willing to remove data, then why stop at one "outlier"?  Why not just remove data wholesale until the fit is the best possible?

How do you go from that $L$ matrix to a plot of any kind?

@Dave One might surmise that the horizontal axis of the plot is the row index while the vertical axis is for the values of $L.$
